# How to convert this query into join query

Tags: mysql

Please convert the following query into join query without using subquery in mysql

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.avatar, u.slug, u.location
FROM user_registration as u
WHERE u.id <>'3' AND u.id NOT IN (SELECT f.user_id FROM followers as f WHERE f.follower_id ='3')
order by id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to port your query over to a join would be to left join `user_registration` with a subquery on `followers`.  The criteria for a record to be retained is that the user registration id is not `'3'`, and also that record did not match to anything in the join with the subquery on `followers`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.avatar, t1.slug, t1.location
FROM user_registration t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT f.user_id
    FROM followers f
    WHERE f.follower_id = '3'
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.id <> '3' AND t2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.id
```

I *think* the following query should also work:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.avatar, t1.slug, t1.location
FROM user_registration t1
LEFT JOIN followers t2
    ON t1.id = t2.user_id AND t2.follower_id = '3'
WHERE t1.id <> '3' AND t2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Comment: Empty record found.

Comment: @AnkitVirani Sorry, I left out the `ON` clause.  Could you try it again?

Comment: Thank you for helping us :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a join query that doesn't use a sub-select:

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.name, u.avatar, u.slug, u.location
FROM
    user_registration u
    LEFT JOIN followers f ON (u.id = f.user_id AND f.follower_id = 3)
WHERE
    u.id <>'3' AND
    f.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY id
```

Note that if you use a sub-select (as in few other answers), even if you're joining its result, MySQL is still likely using internal temporary tables (that lack any indexes) to perform the joins. If you join the actual tables, you retain all the benefits of joining using existing indexes. You can always run `EXPLAIN` to see what indexes are getting used.

Comment: Thank you for helping us :)

Comment: How can enable EXPLAIN in PhpMyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.avatar, u.slug, u.location
FROM user_registration as u
LEFT JOIN followers ON followers.follower._id = u.id
AND u.id <>'3'
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
 SELECT u.id, u.name, u.avatar, u.slug, u.location
    FROM user_registration u LEFT JOIN followers f
    ON u.id=f.user_id
    WHERE u.id <>'3' AND f.follower_id <>'3'
    order by u.id;
```

Comment: This query uses the old style pre-ANSI 92 syntax, which is considered discouraged by many.

Comment: Edited Accordingly